# Priming plaster wall for wallpaper

Tags: waterproofing, plaster, primer, wallpaper

I was wondering about priming, and possibly partially water proofing a plaster wall for wallpaper. Right now it is mostly covered by drywall mud to iron out the original (110 yr old) uneven surface but right underneath is plaster (about 3/4" thick) over brick. I would like to also apply any treatment that would act as, however modest, baffle against water penetration between the wall substrate and the wallpaper (minimize) as it may be exposed to accidental leak from the roof above. But my priorities are proper priming first and water insulation second.

E.g. can I just apply the wallpaper on the sanded drywall mud over plaster or should I first prime it with something like Killz 2?

Comment: Gardz by Zinsser.

Comment: I would be worried that waterproofing an previously porous wall could lead to moisture build-up inside the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can wallpaper directly over the wall, but it is not recommended. Prepare for the future, you may want to change the wallpaper someday. If you don't use an appropriate primer you will never be able to remove the wallpaper without damaging the wall.

Comment: Thanks but this is not an answer

Comment: @amphibient Looks like it answers the question to me: "can I just apply the wallpaper on the sanded drywall mud over plaster or should I first prime it with something like Killz 2?" Am I missing something?